# Python Pandas - Evenly distribute numeric values to nearest rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

Suppose I have a data set like:

```
> NaN NaN NaN 12 NaN NaN NaN NaN 10 NaN NaN NaN NaN 8 NaN 6 NaN
```

I want to distribute the values as evenly as possible between values of their surrounding `NaN`s. For example the value 12 should take into consideration of their surrounding `NaNs`, and distribute them evenly until it touches the 2nd non-`NaN` value's `NaN`s.

For example the 1st 12 should only take into consideration of his closest NaNs.

```
> NaN NaN NaN 12 NaN NaN
```

The output should be:

```
2 2 2 2 2 (Distributed by the 12)

2 2 2 2 2 (Distributed by the 10)

2 2 2 2 (Distributed by the 8)

2 2 2 (Distributed by the 6)

> NaN NaN NaN 12 NaN NaN NaN NaN 10 NaN NaN NaN NaN 8 NaN 6 NaN

> 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I was originally thinking about using smoothers, such as the interpolate function in Pandas. It does not have to be lossless, meaning that we can lose or get more than the sum in the progress. Are there any libraries that can perform this kind of distribution vs using a lossy smoother?

Comment: What happens when distance in the same? e.g. if it was `7` and `6` in the end, how would you distribute the values?

Comment: Then you do not distribute 7, but distribute the 6.

Comment: And what do you mean by "approach using algorithms"? You have a preference to code the process yourself rather than using a package, Is that it?

Comment: I think it’s a bad statement. Let me remove it.

Comment: If there’s a library that can do this, then great!

Comment: The only thing ambiguous in your question is the last part. You have `8 NaN 6 NaN`. The middle `NaN` has the same distance between `6` and `8`. Why shouldn't it be `2 2 3 3` in the end? i.e. `6` distributed only with the last `NaN` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be 2 2 3 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`interpolate(method='nearest')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and finally [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Short version:

```
>> series = pd.Series(x).interpolate(method='nearest').ffill().bfill()
>> series.groupby(series).apply(lambda k: k/len(k))

[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

---

To illustrate what's happening, create your `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["x"] = x
```

where `x` is the series you gave. Now:

```
>>> df["inter"] = df.x.interpolate(method='nearest').ffill().bfill()
>>> df["inter"] = df.groupby("inter").inter.apply(lambda k: k/len(k))

>>> df

    x     inter
0   NaN   2.0
1   NaN   2.0
2   NaN   2.0
3   12.0  2.0
4   NaN   2.0
5   NaN   2.0
6   NaN   2.0
7   NaN   2.0
8   10.0  2.0
9   NaN   2.0
10  NaN   2.0
11  NaN   2.0
12  NaN   2.0
13  8.0   2.0
14  NaN   2.0
15  6.0   3.0
16  NaN   3.0
```